# How to make delimeter with selectsize.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I need your help, i didn't understand how to make a delimeter with selectsize.js
For example, when i put "1,2,3,4,5"
I want to see this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K0Jf.png)
But i see this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQgGO.png)

My code:

```js
$(function () {
   $(".select-key").selectize({
      "delimiter": ",",
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.13.3/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>

<select multiple class="form-control select-key" id="sel2" name="key-list[]">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: When I run the example here I see the same as you shown in the first image

Comment: https://skr.sh/v9djxxoLDiM You can see video, i want when i put "1,2,3,4,5" I want to see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K0Jf.png